# Belgium Additional Contribution long stay (D) visa

Tags: visas, schengen, belgium

I am attempting to apply for a Belgium long stay (D) visa for a study abroad program.  Since March 2, 2015 an additional contribution of 215 Euro is required to be paid to the Immigration Office bank account.

The contribution needs to be net 215 Euro on the Immigration Office bank account side.  I have the bank fee for my originating bank, the bank fee for the intermediary bank, but my US bank is unable to determine the bank fee on the Belgium side.  I need to know what, if any, the international wire fee for the Immigration office bank account at bpost is.  I have contacted Consulate General for Belgium in both New York and Atlanta and they have no information. I have an email out to bpost, but no response.

Has anyone successfully completed a net 215 Euro to the Immigration Office of Belgium and if yes, how did you accomplish this?

Comment: I believe long stay visa belong into Expatriates rather than Travel.

Comment: Flagged to move to Expatriates.

Comment: OP has asked on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/belgium-long-stay-d-visa-additional-contribution-requirement), so no migration necessary.